# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am using the following JS code in a function to logout of a website on Chrome:

```
var docLogout = document.querySelector('.submit.logout');
docLogout.click();
```

I get error:

```
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined'
```

This is because I need to make sure that the class of the button exists first and I do that with following steps which I figured out:

- Use "select an element in page to inspect it" button (first button on the far left of the developer tools)
- Click on the Logout button to inspect it
- The Elemets tab opens up
- The Elements field highlights the line `<button type="submit" class="submit logout">Log out</button>`
- I then click on the Console tab
- Paste my code again and it works (any button on the same page will work thereafter)

How can I avoid this manual step of making the elements be known first with the above steps? is there a way to expand all DOM elements initially when the website loads a different page to avoid "Cannot read property 'click' of undefined'" error without any human interaction of using the inspect elements button first?

NOTE: at least explain the donevotes so that I can engage you!!!!!!

Comment: you misspelled ('.submit.logut'); shouldn't it be .logout?

Comment: @Icewine I fixed the mispell (I was typing in manually) the question still stands though

Comment: Did you try wrapping your code in a `DOMContentLoaded` listener?

Comment: no i did not, furthermore, if i have 2 buttons on the same page, i.e one button to logout and another to select a different tab, the code to click a button will only work for the button i inspected, if i inspect button A I can click button A with JS and will get error if it tries to click button B, if I inspect button B JS it will click button B and give error if it tries to click button A, however if button B C D are of the same type (example choosing different tabs) they will all work if I inspect only one of them..

Answer (score 2):

`docLogout` is `undefined`, meaning there is no element in the document with classes `submit` and `logout` *at this time*

If it is possible to manually inspect the page and find `<button class="submit logout">`, then the code is probably running before the `<button>` was attached to the `DOM`.

**Solution: Make sure the code is running after the `DOM` has attached the `<button>`.**

One way to do this is put `<script>` just before the `</body>` closing tag, e.g.,

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <button class="submit logout">Logout</button>
    <script>
      /* button is attached to the DOM at this point */
      const docLogout = document.querySelector('.submit.logout')
      docLogout.click()
    <script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Another solution is to run code after the `window`'s `load` event, e.g.,

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.querySelector('.submit.logout').click()
})
```

If possible, I would recommend giving the button an `id` and using `document.getElementById`

Answer (score -1):

seems you are not using the selector correctly. 
you can put the break put on this line check why it is coming null / undefined 
use f12 and go to source and search the js file and put the break-point on this give line to debug it.